# My HTML5/Javascript code won't perform the same function multiple times?

Tags: javascript, html, io

I've been troubleshooting a small piece of code meant to allow a user to select a local file, input the text contents of the local file into a variable, and then dump the variable value into a textarea.

This is all working great, and the user can choose a file and then see the contents of the file in my textarea. Here's the problem, I have a button called "ClearAll" and it clears the textarea value. If the user then selects a local file again, nothing happens, and the textarea is never populated by the local file contents.

So in summary, selecting a local file once works, but the second time doesn't.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="file" /><br>
<script>
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
        if (!files.length) {
          alert('Please select a file!');
          return;
        }
        var file = files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
                document.getElementById('myInput').textContent = evt.target.result;
            }  
        };
        reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
    }
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

...And I also have a button that successfully calls a function to clear the textarea by just settings its value to `=""`. For some reason the textarea population only works once. Can anyone see why this is?

Quick comment: I thought maybe if I change the contents of `files` when the ClearAll button is activated, it might reset things, but no luck.

Comment: Anyone have some insight? I'd be happy to try any suggestions, just point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the last line. the event change would not fire twice when you pick the same file name.
rename the file and see it works.